# How to get previous (last) added item id by current logged in user in a list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, custom-list

How can I get the previously (last) added item id by the current logged in user in a custom list?

I created a custom list to get username, [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address), and check-in time. From a web part the user who logged in will submit these fields. Next time when he logs in again to the site I want to rerun the previously added IP address, check-in time, ID, so that I can do some calculations. So how can I get these things done?

Answer (score 2):

Sharepoint generates ids which are always unique and incremental. So you could write a CAML query for the List to get all the items added for the current user and then select the ListItem with max value of id.

Comment: Hi Pushpendra, can you give me any like that have simple example using CAML.

Answer (score 0):

This query will get you the latest item added by a user in the List.

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where>" +
                  "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Author' /><Value Type='User'>user.Name</Value></Eq>" +
                "</Where>" +
              "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
query.RowLimit = 1;
query.ViewFields = "";
query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
```

Comment: Should that be descending to get the latest item?

Comment: Yes..it should be descending...